# Total duration of all audio files of an array in Swift

Tags: swift

How to get the total duration of all audio files of an array in Swift 3 / 4 ?
["A","x","B","y","C","x","D","y"]

F. i. duration in sec:
x : 1s
y : 1s
A : 5s
B : 10s
C : 20s
D : 25s

So the total duration of the above array is 64 sec.

The array can mutate by user selection via SegmentedControl (f. i.: repeat "x" 2 times & "y" 3 times):
["A","x","x","B","y","y","y","C","x","x","D","y","y","y"]

Is there a posibility to get the total duration from audio files by a list or is there a solution using a function / methode from AVFoundation or anything elses?

The duration (in sec) of each audio files are known and given in a list.

Comment: You could create `AVAsset` instances from the URLs, map the objects to their `duration` and sum it up.

Comment: Are x, y, A, B, C, D numbers or do they have an `s` at the end?

Comment: What are the objects in your array? Your example is strings. Are those filenames? If so what kinds of sounds files are they, and how are you loading and playing them?

Comment: @Duncan C Your example is strings. Are those filenames? YES. What kinds of sounds files are they? m4a. And how are you loading and playing them? AVAudioPlayer

Comment: @vadian Sounds easy, but how do I do it. Especially how to create AVAsset instances from the URLs and map the objects to their duration?

Answer (score 0):

If your "list" of durations is an array of say Int values (as in number of seconds e.g.) then you can reduce (sum) the content of the array like this.

```
let durations = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let durationsSum = durations.reduce(0, { x, y in
    x + y
 })
```

Comment: Or `durationSum = durations.reduce(0, +)`